# Market Data on Corporate bond yield

Tags: credit-ratings

I am looking for some historical data on the Corporate bond yield time series for different Credit ratings and maturities which typically S&P/Moody's offers.

Is there any possibilities to get such data available on free?

Does Bloomberg offer such data?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

St. Louis Fed's FRED site has data for some of the ICE BoA credit indices, e.g. https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/BAMLH0A0HYM2EY. Might not be as granular as you want as you mentioned both ratings and maturities - I'm not aware of any free sources for that. Bloomberg has their own indices though offhand I don't know what rating/maturity combinations they cover.